# Print a space separated list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the common "print a character after every item in a list, except the last one" problem.

I do not want to use list indexes. There are a couple of simple ways to do this in Python, but I am not sure how to apply them to my code.

Is there a more readable/couple liner way to do this?

```
def echo(*args):
    for data in args:
        if data is args[-1]:
            ender = ''
        else:
            ender = ' '

        if isinstance(data, six.string_types) \
                    or isinstance(data, six.integer_types):

            print_(data, end=ender)
        else:
            op = getattr(data, '__str__', None)
            if op:
                print_(data.__str__(), end=ender)
            else:
                LOG.error("echo called with an unsupported data type")
    print_('')
```

**Note**: Code works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: **(I am not able to solve the "except the last one")** , **Is there a way to do this without the trailing space.** -> sounds like you want us to fix it. This is not within the scope of the site. Members can only review working code. And working code means it gives you what you expect in the end or try to achieve.

Comment: @Bhathiya-JaDogg-Perera Fixed. My code now works. But is ugly

Comment: @Bhathiya-JaDogg-Perera Yes. It must work on both versions, hence why i am using six

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might be misreading your code, but it looks like all you want is:

```
def echo(*args):
    six.print_(*args, sep=" ", end="")
```

For something a bit more manual:

```
def echo(*args):
    six.print_(" ".join(map(str, args)), end="")
```

---

In terms of reviewing your actual code, on top of the issues Morwenn raises, note that:

```
op = getattr(data, '__str__', None)
if op:
```

simplifies to:

```
if hasattr(data, '__str__'):
```

However, it is rare to call magic methods directly in Python; normally you'd just do `str(data)` and let Python call `__str__`. This is safer, as although an old-style class may not implement `__str__`, you can still get e.g. `'<foo.bar object at 0x...>'` via `str(...)`.

---

I would include the filtering as a separate function:

```
def valid(arg):
    """Include a docstring to explain your filtering rules."""
    if (isinstance(data, (six.string_types, six.integer_types)) or
        hasattr(data, '__str__')):
        return True
    LOG.error("echo called with an unsupported data type")
    return False
```

Then `echo` can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def echo(*args):
    six.print_(*filter(valid, args), sep=" ", end="")
```

Comment: It seems that there is also the "type handling" part. I don't know what it really adds to `print_` though.

Comment: @Morwenn I couldn't figure out exactly what cases the OP was trying to cover with that either. Specifically trying to find and call `__str__` seems a bit odd.

Comment: I have been trying to figure it out for 20 minutes too, but I am as clueless as you are :/

Comment: @Morwenn the main thing is that If I call echo on an object that doesnt have a `__str__` method, or is a scalable, I want to log it, and not print it.

Comment: @Humdinger I have added this to the end of my answer.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `six.print_()` instead of `from __future__ import print_function` in this case? Why would you use `" ".join(map(str, args))` instead of `*args` here?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian not if you're only supporting 2.6 and later, I don't think, but I kept what the OP was using.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: the question has [tag:python-2.7] tag. You don't need to support python 2.6. Anyway, Python 2.6 supports `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 3):

You could probably write a nested function that does the `print` and then you can handle the number of the iteration in the main function:

```
def echo(*args):

    # print a value with regard to its type
    def do_echo(data, ender):
        if isinstance(data, six.string_types) \
                    or isinstance(data, six.integer_types):

            print_(data, end=ender)
        else:
            op = getattr(data, '__str__', None)
            if op:
                print_(data.__str__(), end=ender)
            else:
                LOG.error("echo called with an unsupported data type")

    # print all the values but the last one
    for arg in args[:-1]:
        do_echo(arg, ender=' ')

    # print the last value
    do_echo(args[-1], ender='\n')
```

That was for the refactoring of the code logic. Now, I also have a couple of remarks:

- If `args` is empty, `args[-1]` will raise an `IndexError`. Therefore, it would be good to write this instead:

  ```
  # print the last value
  if args:
      do_echo(args[-1], ender='\n')
  ```
- The [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the style guide for Python does not like explicit line continuations with the backslash and [prefers implicit line continuations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) with parenthesis:

  ```
  if (isinstance(data, six.string_types) or
      isinstance(data, six.integer_types)):
  ```

  And as pointed by @jonrsharpe in the comments, `isinstance` can take a tuple of types instead of a simple type. Therefore, you can rewrite this condition as:

  ```
  if isinstance(data, (six.string_types, six.integer_types)):
  ```
- Why did you fully qualify `six.string_types` and `six.integer_types` but not `six.print_`? Being consistent with regard to the use of the `six.` prefix would be good.

Comment: Note you can pass a tuple to `isinstance`; `if isinstance(data, (six.string_types, six.integer_types)):`